# How to consume web API service from a webforms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webforms application in a big solution folder with multiple projects. I wanted to consume a web api application which is also a part of the solution. So my client looks like as follows.

```
function GetText() 
{
    $.getJSON("api/SiteUsers",
        function (data) {
            $("#TestText").append(data);

        });
}
```

and the controller is a simple string returning action.

```
[HttpGet]
public string TestText()
{
    return "this is a text";
}
```

when I try to call the service I get a 404 error the following link could not be found
     http://localhost:1234/MyAspxProj/MyFolder/MyPage/api/SiteUsers

I can understand it is probably because it is trying to find the resource from within the webforms application. How can I call the web api service? I am open to all suggestions and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say your API is hosted on localhost:1111 and your webforms application is hosted on localhost:2222

first make sure you can get the results of the API you just created by going to:

localhost:1111/api/SiteUsers

once you are sure that the above URL is returning what you expect, you can be sure that your API is set-up correctly.

Now lets come to the next issue, accessing API from another application (i.e. not having the same Host as the API i.e. localhost2222)

To access APIs from an application that is on another domain, you need to enable CORS support on the WebAPI. There are manay resources on the internet that will explain you how you can achieve this: [google for enabling cors in web api 2](https://www.google.com.pk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7rNPVJKVEcKq8weS0YGwDw&gws_rd=cr#q=enabling%20cors%20in%20web%20api%202)

Once you have set-up CORS on your web api project, you will be able to access your API from any application.

Remember: you only need to enable CORS if the client is on different domain AND the client is a web based client (which in your case it is i.e. web forms application)

I hope this will give you some direction.

Comment: Thank you!! I am going to look into your answer and let you what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you've provided, it looks to me like you're not putting in the correct url. Assuming your [HttpGet] function is within a file at "api/SiteUsers", you would use a url like this: "api/SiteUsers/TestText"